# Set background image of a div in front of an image?

Tags: css, position, z-index

The site I'm building is https://new.usedmercedesbenz-sales.co.uk

I have a div with a slideshow inside it at the top of the homepage.

I've set the div (.slider-wrapper) to have a background image, this is an PNG image that I'd like overlayed on the slider to give it a rounded bottom effect.

I've also set the div to z-index of 100 and the z-index of the slider to -100, however, the overlay image is appearing behind the slider despite setting z index (I can see it breifly as the page loads).

How do I set the background of the div to be in front of the image slider?

Comment: You can't, by **definition** a background can't be on top of anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should provide your code as text and not a link. Paste the relevant part of your code here and insert them as a js/html/css snippet. We can better understand what you're trying to do and what exactly is your problem if you do so.

Answer (score -1):

create another div and place it right above the div using absolute positioning relative to the div which has the image or you should give z-index to the img tag itself